# Issues with Date Format() Function

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
SELECT b.id, b.user_id, DATE_FORMAT(b.fecha, '%m/%d/%y'), b.titulo, b.contenido, m.name
          FROM blog b, miembros m 
          WHERE b.user_id = m.userID
          ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

Im trying to get b.fecha value, that actually is 2014-05-21, and make it to 05-12-2014. however it wont get the value. How is the correct way to write it?

Comment: whats the field type for b.fecha ?

Comment: the field type is date

Comment: In a MySQL console, select DATE_FORMAT('2014-05-21', '%m/%d/%y') returns 05/21/14. If you want 05-12-2014, then use '%m-%d-%y'. If you don't get either then make sure b.fecha is a valid date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do for 2014-05-21 and make it to 05-12-2014

```
DATE_FORMAT(b.fecha, '%m-%d-%Y') as fecha
```

Comment: alias is entirely optional

Comment: yes just in case needed to use for application to use it like in PHP :)